# Using svg local file instead of icon (from Bootstrap 5 icon to local svg file import)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, svg, bootstrap-5

I am using Bootstrap 5 icons which work really well, but I have a few svg files that I need to include as they are not in the icon collection.

So for the icon button I'm doing this:

```html
<button type="button" class="btn">
      <svg width="2rem" height="2rem" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-file-earmark-medical" fill="#333333" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M4 0h5.5v1H4a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v12a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h8a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V4.5h1V14a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H4a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V2a2 2 0 0 1 2-2z"/>
        <path d="M9.5 3V0L14 4.5h-3A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 9.5 3z"/>
        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M7 5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v.634l.549-.317a.5.5 0 1 1 .5.866L8 7l.549.317a.5.5 0 1 1-.5.866L7.5 7.866V8.5a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-.634l-.549.317a.5.5 0 1 1-.5-.866L6 7l-.549-.317a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.866l.549.317V5.5A.5.5 0 0 1 7 5zm-2 5.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0 2a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5z"/>
      </svg>
    </button>
```

As you can see above it's really busy and I don't know what most of the parameters do as there are 3 paths with lots of stuff in it.

What I want to do is modify the above so I can import a local svg file that I have.

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried using an img tag or an [object tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object)?

Here's an [article](https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/) about using SVGs also.

Comment: There are 3 path tags above...do I need them so it looks the same as the other icons? I don't know what they are for

Comment: You can reference the SVG file with both tags. There's no need to manipulate the SVG unless you want to make changes to it.
Each path "draws" something in your SVG. I checked and the first one draws the rectangle, the second one the little triangle (page fold) and the third one is the "content" of the page in your icon.
The d attribute in each is just the instructions on how the path shoul be constructed.

Answer (score 0):

Using an image tag:

```css
button {
 padding: 20px;
 }
img {
  height: 200px;
  }
```

```html
<button>
  <img src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/alexmwalker/03433aaec5293280f6b896e7a7a2ef1e/raw/08088a2c6f1fd5e363915003dc7e2e34cc04d3ec/alva.svg" />
</button>
```

Using object tag:

```css
button {
padding: 20px

}

object {
height: 200px
}
```

```html
<button>
  <object type="image/svg+xml" data="https://cdn.rawgit.com/alexmwalker/03433aaec5293280f6b896e7a7a2ef1e/raw/08088a2c6f1fd5e363915003dc7e2e34cc04d3ec/alva.svg">
  fallback
</object>
</button>
```